# Getting INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error after upgrading to google maps version 2

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2

I upgrade my monodroid codes from google maps version 1 to google maps version 2 and create an emulator for testing the app. While I removed the reference to android.googlemaps and remove its useslibrary code of the manifest but still I get `INSTALL_FAILER_SHARED)LIBRARY` error.

In addition of above works what should I do for fixing this error?

This is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="20" android:versionName="1.2.1.311" package="my.package">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <!-- Perimission -->
    <permission android:name="my.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="my.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!-- features -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <activity android:name="PropertyImagesActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <!-- Put your Google Maps V2 API Key here. This key will not work for you.-->
        <!-- See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
        android:value="AIzaSyBS5Mg8w_e2sDjlgGenB6s_uSYF0qHrMiM"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

May it be from some thing except than google map?

Comment: did you include the google_play_services library in your project located in ...\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject? If not open it as a project and include it as a library in your project.

Comment: Yes, I include the project in my solution. Actually my project runs on device with google maps but in the emulator without google maps it is not working and show this error. As I know on the version 2 the map is inside googleplayservices and no needs to having google maps install on device. so surely I forgot to remove something related to google maps from my project but I do not know what is this.

Comment: The demo project of xamarin also runs on my emulator but my project do not install.

Comment: Any body can help? :-S

Answer (score 0):

Install com.google.android.gms.apk and com.android.vending-4.2.3.apk on your android device or emulator.